How to use Jenkins git parameter plugin with environment variables
I configured several Jenkins jobs via declarative pipeline. I synced the job names with my gitlab repositories so I can checkout in Jenkins like:
git url: https://gitlab-server/${JOB_BASE_NAME}.git
So I have only one Jenkinsfike stored in a separate repository and I can choose the 'Pipeline script from SCM' option for all my projects.
Now if I want to select a specific branch to build with Git parameter plugin, I set up the parameters section like
gitParameter(...,useRepository: '. *${JOB_BASE_NAME}.git)
But the plugin won't populate the variable and I always get an empty result. How can I configure my pipeline so I get the branches for this repository?
I created a minimal example here:
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin.*/(.*)', defaultValue: 'main', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH', useRepository: '.*${JOB_BASE_NAME}.git'
}
stages {
    stage('Clone repository') {
        steps {
            git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'MyGitToken', url: 'https://MyGitlabServer.com/${JOB_BASE_NAME}.git'
        }
    }
}
}

This works as expected in a Jenkins job but if I put this snippet in a separate repository and use the 'Pipeline script from SCM'-option it does not display my branches anymore.
If I instert a valid URL instead of 'JOB_BASE_NAME', it also works as expected.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
